# Avoid blanks in output loop

Tags: jsp, jstl

I use this JSTL statement ...

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
  <c:out value="${i}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

and the result is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there an easy way to avoid blanks in the output line? I would like to see an output like this:

```
12345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5"><c:out value="${i}"/></c:forEach>
```

or simply

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">${i}</c:forEach>
```